# Click the alphabet twice?

Tags: c++

```
void password()
{
int i=0, j;
char str[30], ch;
gotoxy (23,10);
cout<< "Welcome to our project! \n";
delay (800);
gotoxy (23,11);
cout<< "Please enter the password = ";
while ((ch=getch())!=13)
{
ch=getch();
str[i]=ch;
i++;
clrscr();
gotoxy (20,20);
cout<< "Enter Password = ";
for (j=0; j<i; j++)
cout<< "*";
}
str[i]='\0';
if (strcmp(str,"script")!=0)
{
cout<< endl;
cout<< "Incorrect Password! \n";
cout<< "Access Denied! \n";
getche();
exit (0);
}
}
```

i made this a while back, and i came across a problem. So the problem is that, there are no errors whatsoever when I compile the program and run it. The only issue is that when it asks me to enter the password for the script, I have to PRESS every alphabet TWICE and it shows up once (for example, password is TOLS, I have to press it like TTOOLLSS and it shows up as TOLS). How can I fix it?

Comment: You could have at least formatted the code if you're expecting someone to help you with homework.

Comment: I don't think "alphabet" means what you think it means. Also you should stop writing primordial "C++" from the 1980s on your DOS emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
ch=getch();
```

since you already got the char in the line:

```
while ((ch=getch())!=13)
```